# Organization of Ajax files for autoloading with php

Tags: php, ajax, autoload, organization

I want to use the autoloader in my php project and I don't know if my file organization is viable. Right now my folder is structured this way :

```
-ProjectFolder
   index.php
   -common
      -ajax
         ajax_file.php
      -classes
         MyClass.php
```

In MyClass.php I have the following line of code `namespace common\classes;`.

In index.php I have

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name){
  $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $class_name);
  require "$file.php";
});
```

And so I can call in the index.php file the "test" static method by having the following line in my code :
`common\classes\MyClass::test();`

But index.php is used get answers from ajax_file.php.
If I just call my "test" method by just adding the same line of code into ajax_file.php it tells me that the class can't be found. I guess that it's because it's loaded independently from what's going on in index.php.

I don't know how I can access MyClass from ajax_file.php and I'm not even sure it's possible since I've read some things that seem to indicate it's not possible to "go back" using "../" with the autoloader.

Could you tell me what's the good way do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that your autoloader uses absolute and not relative paths.
This involves defining a base directory for the root namespace corresponding to `projectFolder`.

In index.php:

```php
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    $file = __DIR__ . '/' . str_replace('\\', '/', $class_name);
    require "$file.php";
});
```

You have some examples of autoloader on [php-fig](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/examples/) to comply with the standard (PSR-4).

Note that the **ajax_file.php** file must explicitly include the autoloader (and therefore **index.php**)

Comment: Thank you, I followed your instructions and it works. I've put the autoload function in another file that is included both in index.php and in ajax_file.php. I got to say I don't get how php identifies which folder is the root of the three nor that I undestand how he finds the MyClass.php file.